# Mount all connected drives to their own respective mount points

Tags: mount, opensuse, fdisk

How can I mount every single hard drive connected to a computer (preferably excluding flash drives and CDs) to it's own mount point.
For example, if my connected drives looked like so:

```
DISK                     MEDIA TYPE
/dev/disk0               INTERNAL
    /dev/disk0
    /dev/disk0s1
/dev/disk1               REMOVABLE
    /dev/disk1
/dev/disk2               INTERNAL
    /dev/disk2
```

I would want to mount every drive and partition, unless it is removable (flash drive), or a CD.
The mount points should be in there own folders, ex: `/dev/disk0` would be mounted to `/home/root/mounts/fooName1`, and `/dev/disk2` would be mounted to `/home/root/mounts/fooName2`. If this is possible without any extra programs, great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty standard to specify the fixed mounting points and is done in `/etc/fstab`.  See [man fstab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html) for details.

Note that it is a really bad idea to mount partitions in a home directory.  It usually causes more confusion and disorganization than any advantage it could have.  Permissions can make them available only to root if you chose to anyways.

Comment: I need to only mount internal disks though. How do I do that?

Comment: Refer to the link I included for the `fstab` man page.  Looking at your current `/etc/fstab` file can already point you in the right direction.